# Having issue with UITextField and UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in my `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`.  I have 11 cells total.  When I enter text in a cell, and scroll the cell off the screen, that text is getting cleared.

It seems like maybe the cells are being dequed or deallocated.  There are only 11 so it doesn't be too much of an issue, but how can I make all the cells's `textFields` visible within this view at all times?

This is the code I'm using.  Is it because I don't have a datasource such as an array or something?  I'm pulling the text initally from the `childAppointmentDictionary` if there is text from the server, otherwise the user enters text and I save it to an `NSString`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CellIdentifier = @"textCell";
    VitalsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
            cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
            self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
            cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"pulse"];
            self.pulseTextField = cell.textField;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == temperatureTextField){
        self.temperatureString = self.temperatureTextField.text;
    } 
    else if (textField == pulseTextField){
        self.pulseString = self.pulseTextField.text;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Can I perhaps duplicate the look of this `UITableView` using a `UIScrollView`?  This would solve some of the issues I'm having?

Answer (score 0):

The cells off-screen get reused. That's normal behavior. You need to fill in the proper methods to make sure their content gets refreshed.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

As Gabriele pointed out, you need to use tableView:cellForRow: to replace the text.

Comment: Should I add each cell's `textField.text` to `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` instead?

Comment: The text you want in your cells needs to be stored elsewhere for reuse in the forRowAtIndexPath, or regenerated in the forRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: Ok, right now the initial text is stored in `childAppointmentDictionary` right?  Its just the new text if I add text of edit it that is not being stored anywhere based on my code, right?

Comment: Ok, so I'll make a new dictionary and have it use the same keys, and if the user enters text, add it to that key in the new dictionary.  That should work right?  Where would I actually place the code to do this?  Like `self.myDictionary = [self.temperatureTextField.text objectForKey: @"temperature"];`

Comment: I'm not really sure about where you should do that. The point of the question is to deal with your disappearing text. So as Gabriele says, you need to set up tableView:cellForRow: to put the text back in. Where you store the text is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok makes sense, I think I need one unified dictionary that pulls data from the server, then I can overwrite it when user edit's text.  Cause now it pulls from server, then writes to string, so when the cell is reloaded again, its pulling text from server instaed of from that string.

Answer (score 0):

When the cell go offScreen all the views inside are deallocated for performance reason. It does not store your text (NSString) and when the cell go to screen the TableView redraw it but with no Text.

Your Text (NSString) have to be considered as your Model. So in tableView:cellForRow: you need to set every time the NSString you want as text.

## Some Code

Your approach is near to be good but you need to allocate cell with cellIdentifier at least 1 time. The cell needs to be subclassed using textfield or similar, as you have done I suppose, and use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: to retrieve the cell template from the tableView.
Once you retrieved the cell template you are allowed to configure the text for your textfields. This Textfields so are filled every time tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath get called by your tableViewDataSource using NSString stored inside your Model (the NSDictionary in your case).
If you are layering a static number of row for you table I suggest you to use an enum to keep your code more readable. I suggest also to read [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1). It's very very useful.
Hope this help.

```
typedef enum {
    kCellRowTemperature = 0,
    kCellRowPulse
} CellRowTAG;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"textCell";
    VitalsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[VitalsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case kCellRowTemperature:
            cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Temperature";
            cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"];
            self.temperatureTextField = cell.textField;
            break;
        case kCellRowPulse:
            cell.vitalsLabel.text = @"Pulse";
            cell.textField.text = [self.childAppointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"pulse"];
            self.pulseTextField = cell.textField;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this based on the code I have in the question?

Comment: Should I add each cell's textField.text to NSDictionary or NSArray?